# Can we create application which run on Android TV ,tablet and Android Phones?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-tv

I just want to know that can i create one android studio project which can run on Android TV, tablets, and Android smartphones?

Comment: Please read the question first, I am want to create an application which runs all three platform TV, tablets and mobile in a single project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Your app needs to declare the intent filter for both mobile and Android TV. Typically these should be different activities since the UI is usually different, but they can also point to the same activity if you're programmatically choosing the correct UI based on the device.

Here's an example of the manifest:

```
<application
  android:banner="@drawable/banner" >
  ...
  <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

  </activity>
</application>
```

If you're starting a completely fresh Android Studio project, I'd recommend starting with a mobile template first and then manually updating the manifest. See the [getting started guide](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start) for more info, including the intent filter, the banner, the "leanback" feature, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.While starting new project there is option for selecting template for Phone and tablet,Wear OS,Android TV etc like below image.
[image]

Comment: it only works for mobiles and tablets. what about TV?

Comment: @PankajJangid you can select Android TV 3rd tab in above image to create TV app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the leanback support library in order for your app to support Android TV.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/leanback) for the implementation steps.

Comment: The leanback library is not a requirement for running an app on TV; it just provides templates to make the process easier.